PMR `unordered_map` with `unique_ptr` data
I want to use a custom allocator with the std::pmr::unordered_map so that its elements are allocated using the same custom allocator, and so on down the chain. However, I ran into a problem when creating a tree like data structure with it.
#include <unordered_map>

class A {
public:
    using allocator_type = Mallocator; // Do NOT remove. Needed to enable scoped allocation for the class.

    using NodeMap = std::pmr::unordered_map<std::size_t, A>;

    NodeMap nodes_ = {};
};

This compiles on Windows MSVC compiler but does NOT with GCC on Linux. The Linux compiler rightfully rejects the code since class A is incomplete and we are using it in NodeMap.
My instinct is to use std::unique_ptr instead in the map - using NodeMap = std::pmr::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::unique_ptr<A>>;. But, wouldn't both it, and the object A it points to be allocated outside my custom allocator. Is there a PMR version of std::unique_ptr?
Please suggest alternatives.
EDIT2:
MRE at godbolt. As Ted points out, the latest compilers somehow do not throw errors.
EDIT1:
Error output from GCC
pt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ?struct std::pair?:
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/ext/aligned_buffer.h:91:28: required from ?struct __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer >?
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable_policy.h:234:43: required from ?struct std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base >?
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable_policy.h:268:12: required from ?struct std::__detail::_Hash_node_value, false>?
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable_policy.h:277:12: required from ?struct std::__detail::_Hash_node, false>?
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1812:13: required from ?struct std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc, false> > >?
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable_policy.h:811:13: required from ?struct std::__detail::_Insert_base, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to, std::hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits >?
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1004:12: required from ?struct std::__detail::_Insert, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to, std::hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits, false>?
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/hashtable.h:180:11: required from ?class std::_Hashtable, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to, std::hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits >?
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/unordered_map.h:105:18: required from ?class std::unordered_map, std::equal_to, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator > >?
fileA.cpp:121:20: required from here
/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:218:11: error: ?std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second? has incomplete type


"... rightfully rejects ..." - What error do you get from gcc? I don't see why it should give you an error.

@TedLyngmo Added the error output to the question details. Thanks!

Ok, gcc 13 and up accepts the code and so does clang, given that you actually do have a Mallocator.

@TedLyngmo You are right! https://godbolt.org/z/c7WY4rPbr . I felt it was right to not compile with an incomplete type but something seems to have changed within the latest compiler versions. I still cannot change the toolchain and am looking for alternatives.
